# Datatables search input doesn't work in OctoberCMS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables, octobercms

I'm working with Datatables server-side processing in OctoberCMS.
Everything works fine but search input doesn't work.
Search input works fine as I tried it in client-side processing.

Datatables part Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableId = "datalist";
  var table = $('#' + tableId).DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: {
          url: '/ajax?tb={{ tableName|raw() }}&fd={{ fields|raw() }}',
          type: 'GET',
          //tb: 'BYAPPS_apps_data',
          error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
      },
      paging: true,
      pageLength: 50,
      "info": false,
      "autoWidth": true,
      "fixedHeader": false,
      "responsive": true,
      "orderClasses": false,
      "stateSave": true,
      "dom": 'Bfrtip',
      "buttons": [
          'excel', 'copy'
      ],
  });

  $('.dataTables_filter input').bind('keyup', function () {
      console.log('here');
        table.search(this.value).draw();
    });
});
```

Ajax part PHP file

```php
function onStart()
{
   $table = $_GET['tb'];
   $length = $_GET['length'];
   $start = $_GET['start'];
   $fields = explode("|", $_GET['fd']);

   $result = DB::table($table)->skip($start)->limit($length)->get();
   $data = array();

   foreach($result as $row) {
      $sub_array = array();

      for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {
            $sub_array[] = $row->{$fields[$i]};
      }
      $data[] = $sub_array;
   }

   $output = array(
     "draw" => intval($_GET['draw']),
     "recordsTotal" => DB::table($table)->count(),
     "recordsFiltered" => DB::table($table)->count(),
     "data" => $data,
   );

   echo json_encode($output);
}
```

How can I fix this and make the search input work?

Comment: Do you have a routes file for the ajax endpoint?

Comment: No, I'm doing this in OctoberCms and it doesn't have one. Should I make a routes file?

Comment: For now, I solved this problem by adding a query using ``$_GET['search']['value']``. But I think it isn't the right way. It doesn't fit in Laravel way(?).

Comment: You can add a routes.php file in octoberCMS inside the plugin directory. then simply point your ajax request to your route.

Comment: You will also need to add a controller in your normal plugin controllers folder. You can do this by creating a controller that extends Illuminate\Routing\Controller.